# Por que o estilo não está sendo aplicado?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

Tenho o seguinte programa:

```
program Paker;

{$APPTYPE GUI}

uses
  Vcl.Forms, Classes, SysUtils, Vcl.StdCtrls;

var
    FForm : TForm;
    FModeComb : TComboBox;
    FBtn : TButton;

begin
    Application.Initialize;
    Application.CreateForm(TForm, FForm);

    FForm.BorderStyle := bsDialog;
    FForm.Caption := 'Choose a Mode:';
    FForm.Position := poDesktopCenter;
    FForm.OldCreateOrder := false;
    FForm.PixelsPerInch := 96;

    FModeComb := TComboBox.Create(nil);
    FModeComb.Parent := FForm;
    FModeComb.Left := 4;
    FModeComb.Top := 4;
    FModeComb.Width := 152;
    FModeComb.Style := csDropDownList;
    FModeComb.Items.Add('Encrypting resource files.');
    FModeComb.Items.Add('Mixing files into packages.');
    FModeComb.ItemIndex := 0;

    FBtn := TButton.Create(nil);
    FBtn.Parent := FForm;
    FBtn.Left := FModeComb.Width + 8;
    FBtn.Top := 4;
    FBtn.Width := 64;
    FBtn.Height := FModeComb.Height;
    FBtn.Caption := 'Go!';

    FForm.ClientHeight := FModeComb.Height + 4 + 4;
    FForm.ClientWidth := 12 + FModeComb.Width + FBtn.Width;

    Application.Run;

end.
```

O problema é que os componentes estão demostrando o visual antigo dos Delphis 7 e anteriores. Estou deixando alguma configuração pra trás? Alguém sabe como habilitar o estilo normal das aplicações do XE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inclua em `Uses` a *unit* `Vcl.XPMan` isso deverá aplicar o estilo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Todas as aplicações de formulário criadas automaticamente incluem XPMan e eu nunca vi?

Comment: Então como é feito nas aplicações criadas pelo menu? Se souber, pode incluir no corpo da resposta, pra ficar mais completa.

Comment: É possível criar "Formulários VCL" em runtime?

Comment: @Guill Segundo [essa resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4354794/1608936) no *SOEn* é possível, porém **trabalhoso**, o melhor modo seria utilizar o `XPManifest` para mostrar o efeito.